# Flutter Banner on the top of the app (Android)

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

Hello, i want to delete the banner that appears at the top of the MaterialApp only happens on Android, in iOs i don't have that issue.

I used the very_good cli

I tried to view if the android_manifest.xml have some information but i didn't find anything that could help me.

I am expecting to delete the black banner with the appName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an `AppBar` which is located inside a `Scaffold`. Try looking for it in the project and delete it.

Alternatively this could be based on the android activitie's theme. In the android specific module, open the manifest.xml file and check which themes are used in the activities:

```
<manifest ...>
   <application
        ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            ...
        </activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In this case, flutter uses `LaunchTheme` and after the launch it applies `NormalTheme`.

Open then the styles.xml file (usually located at: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`). Find the styles that match the styles which are used by the activity and check if they both inherit from a `NoTitleBar` style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```